# WP_Query to get category name in wordpress for custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an issue to get category name on custom post type in wordpress

This is code

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=>'projects',
    'posts_per_page'=>-1,
    'category_name'=>'projects_clients',
    'orderby'=>'name',
    'order'=>'ASC'
);
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace `'category_name'=>'projects_clients'` with `'category'=>'projects_clients'`

Comment: i replaced. but when i use 'echo get_the_category' it display 'array' instead of category name

Comment: it's because it contains an array and `echo` does not print array , post your whole query code where you trying to print it .

Comment: <?php  echo get_the_category();?>

Comment: @Mathur you have a poor history of accepting answers to questions. Please give the people who answer your questions with a little recognition, all it requires is to upvote / click on the tick icon.

Comment: @David thats why i deleted my answer and didn't proceed further to help ,,, he is asking me to organise the code given by him by asking many times and gave me inside comment instead of posting inside question.

Comment: completely understandable @ArshSingh :)

Comment: guys i am new here and i dont know more about how to manage

Comment: a few points to help -1. code in comments is very hard to read, see the edit button above? if you click on that you can edit the original question. 2. A small output is ok `once its in ticks and as short as this`. 3. Always respond to answers, even if incorrect they are basing the answer on their experience and the information given which is frequently not enough.4. Accept/ upvote answers that are correct and upvote those that are close and help you understand a bit. It would be a good idea to click on your name above and review previous answers given.

Comment: for this q, you need to identify whether `'projects_clients'` is a term saved in category or a custom taxonomy which its format suggests it is, change `category_name` to `taxonomy` in your args

Comment: @thanks David for suggestion and i used taxonomy instead of category but still its not working

Comment: ok you need to give us more information, is it a custom taxonomy or a term you want to query by?

Comment: Thanks its get solved now